# How to plot Histogram on specific data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I am reading CSV file:

```
 Notation Level   RFResult   PRIResult   PDResult  Total Result
 AAA       1       1.23        0           2         3.23
 AAA       1       3.4         1           0         4.4
 BBB       2       0.26        1           1.42      2.68
 BBB       2       0.73        1           1.3       3.03
 CCC       3       0.30        0           2.73      3.03
 DDD       4       0.25        1           1.50      2.75
 ...
 ...
```

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.rad_csv('home\NewFiles\Files.csv')
Notation = df['Notation']
Level = df['Level']
RFResult = df['RFResult']
PRIResult = df['PRIResult']
PDResult = df['PDResult']

df.groupby('Level').plot(kind='bar')
```

Above code gives me four different figures. I want to change few things below:

1. I don't want to show the `Level` and `Total Results` bar in graph. How should I remove that?
2. Also, how should I label xaxis and yaxis and title of each plot. So for this, I want to give the title of plot is "level number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
df = pd.read_csv('home\NewFiles\Files.csv')

df.plot(kind='hist', y = ['RFResult', 'PRIResult', 'PDResult'], bins=20)

plt.title('level numbers')
plt.xlabel('X-Label')
plt.ylabel('Y-Label')
```

[image]

> Remember the plot is called by `pandas`, but is based on `matplotlib`. So you can pass additional arguments!

Answer (score 2):

To plot use the following code...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('home\NewFiles\Files.csv')
plt.hist((df['RFResult'],df['PRIResult'],df['PDResult']),bins=10)
plt.title('Level Number')
plt.xlabel('Label name')
plt.ylabel('Label name')
plt.plot()
```